# Excel: Look up for the text contains

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, contains, lookup

I need to do a lookup and return the value based on if the text contains it.

Please see my excel sheet below, What I need is a formula, which will help my 'Category' column to be filled 'Category' column of the look up table.

Note: Kindly see my excel sheet in below link.

[image: data provided by user]

I tried the formula '`=VLOOKUP(B2,A13:B16,2,TRUE)`' but it is not giving the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Byron! I have shared the image link. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: In your example are the values in `B2:B7` the only values you need to look up against of are there other values?

Comment: B2:B7 is just a sample. The actual values are much more and it will be  updated in future by adding more.

Comment: Any thoughts @AlexP .

Comment: And what about the look up table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a slight twist on the normal "find this string inside a list of others".  It requires an array formula that searches for matches using `FIND`.

**Picture of ranges**

[image: ranges and results]

**Formula** in cell `A2` is an array formula (entered with <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER</kbd>) and is copied down for each item.  It searches in the list of `lookup` for an item that is included in `item` and returns the result from `category` associated with `lookup`.

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$4,MIN(IF(IFERROR(FIND($D$2:$D$4,B2)>0,FALSE),ROW($D$2:$D$4)))-ROW($E$1))
```

**How it works**

- `INDEX` is returning from `category` and needs a row number to return
- The row number is determined by using `FIND` which will check if a string is included in part of another string.  In this case, the string to search for is the `lookup` table and we are matching within the `item`.
- `FIND` will return `#VALUE!` if no match is found, this is converted to `FALSE` with `IFERROR` because `#VALUE!` will no work with `MIN` later.
- The `IF` will then return the `ROW` number or `FALSE` for the match that was found.
- `MIN` is used to convert the list of `ROW` numbers to the smallest number.  This means that multiple matches are not handled.
- This `ROW` number is then used as the return for the `INDEX`.  There is an offset applied here `-ROW(E1)` which allows for the data tables to start in a row other `1:1`.